# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, opencv, keras

Hi I have a CNN model which was trained with a input shape 48,48,3.

```
input_shape=(48,48,3)
```

I tried to load the model to use with opencv in realtime but i get a the next error.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 48, 48, 1)
```

The code is

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import numpy as np


face_classifier= cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + '/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
classifier = load_model('/media/carlos/Archivos/MEGA/test2/model.h5')

class_labels=['nostress', 'stress']
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    labels=[]
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_gray=cv2.resize(roi_gray,(48,48),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        if np.sum([roi_gray])!=0:
            roi=roi_gray.astype('float')/255.0
            roi=img_to_array(roi)
            roi=np.expand_dims(roi,axis=0)
            roi=roi.reshape(48,48,3)

            preds=classifier.predict(roi)[0]
            label=class_labels[preds.argmax()]
            label_position=(x,y)
            cv2.putText(frame,label,label_position,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),3)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame,'No Face Found',(20,20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),3)
    
    cv2.imshow('Stress Detector',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I understand that possibly the code to test doesnt have correctly defined the 'shapes', I tried to use reshape, but it doesnt work.

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2304 into shape (48,48,3)
```

Comment: Why are you transforming the image into grayscale? That is exactly what changes from 3 to 1 channels.

Comment: Thanks!. Yes, it was the problem. Finally, i changed "gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)" to "gray=frame" and works. The problem was that the image was transforming into grayscale.

Comment: Yes but that does not answer why you were doing that.